# Главный блок над появляющимся при наведении (изменение  display)

Tags: css3, html, css

Здравствуйте, создал блок один, но он под градиентом и создал второй, у него сначала `display: none;` а при наведении на блок, в котором он находится, у него `display: block;` Дело в том, что при наведении должен появиться просто текст, но появляется он в какой-то рамочке. Сейчас вот такое

```
<div class="work"><img src="images/image.png"><div class="wtext"><a href="#">Link</a></div></div>
```

css

```
.work {
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 3px solid white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px black;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(160,82,45,0.7);
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 3;
}
.wtext a {
    border: 3px solid white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px black;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(160,82,45,0.7);
    border: 5px slim sienna;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin: 195px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 5px 80px 5px 80px;display: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
}
.work:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px black;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(154,205,50,0.7);
}
.work:hover .wtext a {
    display: block;
}
.work img {
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

Теперь при наведении на блок появляется то, что надо, но не могу сделать так, чтобы главный блок work был над появляющимся блоком wtext, да и анимация не работает.

Answer (score 1):

`boder-top: 3px solid yellowgreen;` присутствует. Это рамка сверху. Попробуйте убрать.

Comment: .work {
 padding: 15px;
 margin: 10px;
 float: left;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
   -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
   -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
   -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
   transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.wtext {
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 display: none;
}
.work:hover {
 boder-top: 3px solid yellowgreen;
 box-shadow: 0 0 15px black;
 box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(154,205,50,0.7);
}
.work:hover .wtext {
 backgroung: white;
 display: block;
}

Comment: ну а html почему не показать?? тут же не экстрасенсы сидят.

с того что вижу - boder-top: 3px solid yellowgreen; присутствует. это рамка сверху. попробуйте убрать

Comment: написал выше код в вопросе

Comment: чего вы хотите добиться, объясните русским языком??

чтобы блок со ссылкой появлялся ниже большого блока?

.work {position: relative;} замените fixed - ни к чему оно тут
.wtext a {position:absolute; top:210px; left:20px;} замените fixed добавьте top и left, margin вообще удалите.